# Faster Matrix-Vector-Multiplication (MVM) if the matrix elements are computed on-the-fly

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I am currently working on a Project where I have to calculate the extremal Eigenvalues using the Lanczos-Algorithm. I replaced the MVM so that the Matrix-Elements are calculated on-the-fly, because I will have to calculate the Eigenvalues of real huge matrices. This slows down my Code because for-loops are slower in python thand MVM. Is there any way to improve on my code in an easy way? I tried using Cython but I had no real luck here.

```
for i in range(0,dim):
        for j in range(0,dim):
            temp=get_Matrix_Element(i,j)
            ws[i]=ws[i]+temp*v[j]
```

This replaces:

```
ws = M.dot(v)
```

**Update**
The ,atrix M is sparse and can be stored for "small" systems in a sparse-matrix-format using scipy.sparse. For large systems with up to ~10^9 dimensions I need to calculate the matrix elements on-the-fly

Comment: However, I just noticed a tag [sparse-matrix]. Is you matrix, in fact, sparse? If that is the case, how do you store it?

Comment: @AntonMenshov the matrix I am using is indeed sparse. For "small" systems it's viable to save M in a sparse-matrix-format using scipy.sparse. But I want to get the eigenvalues of huge systems with up to ~10^9 dimensions. This is why I calculate the elements on-the-fly

Comment: Then, I guess, the approach I proposed is justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and fast to implement solution would be to go half-way: precompute one row at a time.

In your original solution (`M.dot(v)`) you had to store `dim x dim` which grows quadratically. If you precompute one row, it scales linearly and should not cause you the troubles (since you are already storing a resultant vector `ws` of the same size).

The code should be along the lines of:

```
for i in range(0,dim):
    temp=get_Matrix_Row(i)
        ws[i]=temp.dot(v)
```

where `temp` is now an `dim x 1` vector.

Such modification should allow more optimizations to happen during the `dot` product without major code modifications.

Comment: But the get_`Matrix_Row(i)` function would have a linear runtime and because it is called in the for-loop I would get the same problem.
I know that my code is slower because I calculate the matrix-Elements on-the-fly. But I want to solve the bottleneck of the python for-loop.

Comment: @Sephka, you still have to compute all the entries (deg*deg) of the matrix. I am suggesting a more cache-friendly and #function calls friendly method, where you also can incorporate some small savings in the `get_Matrix_row()` function.

Comment: Of Course. I misunderstood it at first. I implemented your method and doubled the speed. I will now try to optimize it further. Thanks!